# Insert 2D array elements into 3D array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm looking to insert calculated 2D array elements into a 3D array. The first for loop is how many arrays are required. e.g. when i = 1 the values will go into the first array of the 3D array. The calculated element is seen on the bottom line of code

```
"dctArray[dctRow][dctColumn]".
```

Essentially I'm trying to equate this 2D array value to the first array of the 3D array. So something like this:

```
dctArrayBlocks[i][dctRow][dctColumn] = dctArray[dctRow][dctColumn]
```

But this does not work over the whole array. When I print the individual value of

```
dctArrayBlocks[i][dctRow][dctColumn]
```

it is correct but when I try to print the full array the values come out very incorrect. These outputs are at the bottom.

Thanks and here is the full code:

```
noBlocksOn1Axis = (int(imageLength/blockSize))

        blocksList = []
        previousRow = 0
        for rowBlock in range(noBlocksOn1Axis):
            previousRow = rowBlock * blockSize  
            previousColumn = 0
            for columnBlock in range(noBlocksOn1Axis):
                previousColumn = columnBlock * blockSize
                block = arrayY[previousRow:previousRow+blockSize,previousColumn:previousColumn+blockSize]
                blocksList.append(block)

dctArray = np.zeros((8,8))
dctArrayBlocks = np.zeros(shape = (4,8,8))

for i in range(4):

            for dctRow in range(blockSize):

                for dctColumn in range (blockSize):

                    dctSum = 0

                    for row in range (blockSize):

                        for column in range (blockSize):

                            dctSum = dctSum + blocksList[i][row][column]*math.cos(((2.0*row+1)*dctRow*math.pi)/16.0)*math.cos(((2.0*column+1)*dctColumn*math.pi)/16.0)

                    if(dctRow == 1):
                        cRow = 1/math.sqrt(2)

                    else:
                        cRow = 1

                    if(dctColumn == 1):
                        cColumn= 1/math.sqrt(2)

                    else:
                        cColumn = 1

                    dctArray[dctRow][dctColumn] = 
                    1/4.0*cRow*cColumn*dctSum
                    dctArrayBlocks[i][dctRow][dctColumn] = 
                    dctArray[dctRow][dctColumn]
                    print(dctArrayBlocks[i][dctRow][dctColumn])


        print(dctArrayBlocks)
```

Here is the expected output in list form

```
1160.75
2.15309774781
0.230969883128
0.325283736973
-0.883883476483
-0.332410006991
0.0956708580911
-0.370181380455
-29.1901374775
-0.0455109087818
0.543799659533
0.500630540423
-0.469718941578
0.21007762182
0.340311556876
-0.818563547551
-1.97625897152
1.34074300692
0.265165042945
-1.05682448828
0.450332944883
0.750180006989
0.109834957055
-0.46727710967
-2.38227629503
-0.720900476592
0.904589640549
1.02494023825
-0.564894042278
-1.11318780084
-0.318826625164
-0.627633469915
0.883883476483
0.151835185028
0.760559161902
0.114395653893
0.625
0.465174095446
-0.450332944883
0.732747465688
-1.08735713314
-0.336526203213
0.0151562551075
-0.582857714948
-0.652328957388
0.00538984764367
-0.131671763221
0.541152940662
2.15798528204
-0.175494902565
-0.640165042945
-0.631820804478
0.760559161902
0.315865402699
-0.265165042945
0.266936390222
0.373044516988
-0.443563547551
0.319493333954
-0.857754793709
0.355794721991
0.311551890598
-0.111193339081
0.0606917316737
```

And here is what I'm getting.

```
[[[  1.16075000e+03   2.15309775e+00   2.30969883e-01   3.25283737e-01
    -8.83883476e-01  -3.32410007e-01   9.56708581e-02  -3.70181380e-01]
  [ -2.91901375e+01  -4.55109088e-02   5.43799660e-01   5.00630540e-01
    -4.69718942e-01   2.10077622e-01   3.40311557e-01  -8.18563548e-01]
  [ -1.97625897e+00   1.34074301e+00   2.65165043e-01  -1.05682449e+00
     4.50332945e-01   7.50180007e-01   1.09834957e-01  -4.67277110e-01]
  [ -2.38227630e+00  -7.20900477e-01   9.04589641e-01   1.02494024e+00
    -5.64894042e-01  -1.11318780e+00  -3.18826625e-01  -6.27633470e-01]
  [  8.83883476e-01   1.51835185e-01   7.60559162e-01   1.14395654e-01
     6.25000000e-01   4.65174095e-01  -4.50332945e-01   7.32747466e-01]
  [ -1.08735713e+00  -3.36526203e-01   1.51562551e-02  -5.82857715e-01
    -6.52328957e-01   5.38984764e-03  -1.31671763e-01   5.41152941e-01]
  [  2.15798528e+00  -1.75494903e-01  -6.40165043e-01  -6.31820804e-01
     7.60559162e-01   3.15865403e-01  -2.65165043e-01   2.66936390e-01]
  [  3.73044517e-01  -4.43563548e-01   3.19493334e-01  -8.57754794e-01
     3.55794722e-01   3.11551891e-01  -1.11193339e-01   6.06917317e-02]]
```

Comment: Could you also add the the input data and the expected output? Please look on how to provide  a [Minimal,Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: `x[i][j][k]` indexing works ok for integer values of `i`, `j`, `k`, but the prefered `numpy` syntax is `x[i, j, k]`.  This syntax extends to working with slices (with `:`) and arrays.  You may need to read up on numpy indexing.

Comment: The part where you declare  'blocksList' is missing which seems to be what youa re using to generate the data. Also the part where you create dctArray and dctArrayBlocks is missing which could cause your problem. Try to explaing what you are actually trying to achieve, just by looking at your code, I would say it could be greatly simplified by making use of numpy vectorization, but i can't help you if i don't know what this is supposed to do

Comment: I've added these into the code for you to view. blocksList is a list of block lists. dctArray is an empty 2D array and dctArrayBlocks is an empty 3D array

Comment: The problem occurs when I try print the array as a whole ie "dctArrayBlocks". When I print the individual values in the loop as "dctArrayBlocks[i][dctRow][dctColumn]" they are coming out correct

Comment: Are you sure the output is different? What you posted and seems to be the same thing, just flattened on 1 axis I don't really see a difference in the values

Comment: Yea they're completely different values and I've no idea why

Comment: Ermh just by looking at the first 10 they are the same  1160.75 =  1.16075000e+03     2.15309774781 =   2.15309775e+00    have you taken into account the exponential notation?

Comment: Ahhh didn't realise yea they are the same!! Thanks haha. Is there anyway to suppress this notation?

Comment: Also is this something to divide an image in subblocks and take the fft of every block? If so I would not reinvent the wheel if i were you and look at [numpy.fft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/routines.fft.html)

Comment: For formatting purposes look at the keyword formatter in [this documentantion](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

Comment: It is for DCT compression not sure if FFT is applicable

Comment: It is related but not the same, anyway it is already implemented in [scipy.fftpack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html), i will try to add a  example in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i tried to rewrite the code to make it more pythonic and to show how powerful numpy vectorization can be:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
imageLength = 16
arrayY= np.random.randint(1,255,(imageLength,imageLength))
blockSize = 8

noBlocksOn1Axis = imageLength//blockSize

blocksList = []
previousRow = 0
for rowBlock in range(noBlocksOn1Axis):
    previousRow = rowBlock * blockSize  
    previousColumn = 0
    for columnBlock in range(noBlocksOn1Axis):
        previousColumn = columnBlock * blockSize
        block = arrayY[previousRow:previousRow+blockSize , previousColumn:previousColumn+blockSize]
        blocksList.append(block)

dctArrayBlocks = np.zeros((4,8,8))
bl = np.array(blocksList)

dctSum = np.empty((blockSize,blockSize))
m = np.outer(np.arange(blockSize),np.ones(blockSize))

for i in range(bl.shape[0]):
    for n1 in range(blockSize):
        for n2 in range (blockSize):
            dctSum[n1,n2] = np.sum(
                bl[i] * 
                np.cos((2*m  +1) * n1*np.pi/16.) * 
                np.cos((2*m.T+1) * n2*np.pi/16.)
                )

    dctArrayBlocks[i] = dctSum/4

dctArrayBlocks [:,1,:] /= np.sqrt(2)
dctArrayBlocks [:,:,1] /= np.sqrt(2)
```

This should do exactly what your code was doing, but making use of features of numpy and python.

As i pointed out in the comments, the difference is only a matter of formatting,
Regarding the format you can use something like

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float':lambda x: str(x)})
```

Comment: Thanks pal really appreciate this. I'm getting an error at "dctArrayBlocks[i] = dctSum/4" though saying "index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4". The array is set up as "dctArrayBlocks = np.zeros((4,8,8))"...

Comment: Can you check the shape of bl? I had to generate it using random number starting from a 16x16 image which gives me a (4,8,8) for blockList using your initial piece of code

Comment: I've also added the initial part I used to simulate the input, on a side note, the implementation in scipy cannot be used as it seems it is defined only for a 1D array so it lacks the cos(...)*cos(...) part. Also if you want to use a (4,8,8) shape for the result and discard any extra data coming from blockList you can replace bl.shape[0] with 4

Comment: it returned (400,8,8)

Comment: Yeah your image is way bigger so you are parsing only a few subblcoks and not all of it. If you want just the first 4 subblocks replace bl.shape[0] with 4

Comment: sorry I probably should have made this clear there are actually 400 blocks but for developmental purposes I have substituted it for 4 in some places

Comment: If the calculation are big the implementation of numpy native vectorizaion should be much faster the looping through each element of the matrix 1 by 1. Let me know if it works by replacing the size in the first loop.

Comment: Worked perfectly and almost instantly! Appreciate the help and I will be sure to study numpy vectorization futher, thank you kind sir.

Comment: Just to explain since i didn't really add comments in the code, i collapsed the 2 inner loops by making use of matrix 'm' which is a matrix where every row contains the number of the row (and the transpose using .T which contain in every column the number of the column). Using np.cos on a matrix apply the cos on every element, and multiplying two matrix of the same shape does the multiplication element by element. Finally np.sum sums all the elements in the matrix